# What happens to characters in event leagues?

Tags: path-of-exile

I know that Hardcore character should join Standard upon death. What happens to the various event league characters after they are over, do they get transferred to the normal (Standard) league or are they completely gone? If the character itself gets deleted, does this also apply to equipment and gems acquired during the league?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are transferred to Standard once the league ends.

Comment: Your entire stash will also be transferred and will appear as Remove-Only pages so no worries, everything will still be around, just merged into standard

Comment: Note that this only applies to the major multi month leagues and SOME of the shorter leagues. Some of the short leagues with extreme amounts of loot get voided instead, so everything from that league is erased when it ends except for prizes which get awarded after the league ends.